# example code on how to show Chromecast Volume slider with a soft button not physical volume controls

Tags: android, chromecast, volume

Is there a way to show the volume slider for my chromecast app without having to use the onDispatchKey command?  Netflix has a volume icon in their app and when you tap it, it shows the cast volume slider.

I cannot find an example of this anywhere. Only things through remoteControlClient on a lockscreen.

Thanks,
Reid

Comment: I am not clear what you are having difficulty with; are you asking: (a) how to show a slider, (b) how to sync a slider with the cast system volume or (c) how to reflect the manual changes made to the slider onto the Cast system volume?

Comment: simply showing the slider is sufficient, but it must be the same cast system slider.   I can get a volume slider to show up but it's controlling the devices local audio, not the cast audio.

exactly the same system built in slider as when you tap the physical up/down volume on the device.

Comment: So is it correct that your problem is the following: you are casting some content and you press the hardware volume and a volume slider appears on screen (put out by Android framework) but it controls the local volume and not the remote volume?

Comment: I am casting some content, I can use the volume slider and it controls the correct cast receiver.  The issue I'm having is, how can I have that exact same volume slider appear on the screen (put out by Android framework) but happen when I tap an icon inside my app vs. using the physical hardware volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the platform's overlay window for changing volume, do the following:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME,
        AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```